# Evitar duplicação com PDO no upload de imagem

Tags: mysql, pdo, upload, áudio

Nesse código de upload. A classe faz o upload de um áudio. Tudo funciona bem, mas, não sei como fazer para que "identifica" e "id_user" possam gerir o upload e restringir para apenas quando esses dois forem diferentes ou estiver "vazio", o upload seja realizado. Existe a classe Upload e o comando antes do Upload. Seguem abaixo os códigos.

(01) Esse código está na página do formulário

```
<br><br>
<?php
require_once 'classes/Upload.class-pdo2.php';
require_once 'classes/Funcoes.class.php';

$objUp = new Upload();
$objFc = new Funcoes();

if(isset($_POST['btEnviar'])){
    $objUp->queryInsert();
}

if(isset($_POST['btAlterar'])){
    $objUp->queryUpdate();
}

if(!empty($_GET['acao'])){
    switch($_GET['acao']){
        case 'edit': $slt = $objUp->querySelecionar($_GET['id']); break;
        case 'delet': $objUp->queryDelete($_GET['id']); break; 
    }
}
?>
```

---

```
//<br><br>
<?php<br>
require_once "Conexao.class-pdo.php";<br>
require_once "Funcoes.class.php";<br><br>
class Upload{<br><br>
    //ATRIBUTOS PRIVADOS<br><br>
    private $con;<br>
    private $objfc;<br>
    private $idUploadArquivo;<br>
    private $tipo;<br>
    private $id_user;<br>
    private $legenda;<br>
    private $identifica;<br>
    private $arquivo;
<br><br><br>
    //CONSTRUTOR<br>
    public function __construct(){<br>
        $this->con = new Conexao();<br>
        $this->objfc = new Funcoes();<br>
    }<br><br>

    //METODOS MÁGICOS<br><br>
    public function __set($atributo, $valor){<br>
        $this->$atributo = $valor;<br>
    }<br>
    public function __get($atributo){<br>
        return $this->$atributo;<br>
    }<br>

    <br><br>

    /**<br>
     1º PARTE (VARIAVEIS E TRY-CATCH) - <br>
     O ESSA PARTE SEM FAZER O CADASTRO DAS INFORMACOES DO UPLOAD<br>
    **/<br>



    public function queryInsert(){<br>
        try{<br>
            $this->aula = $_POST['aula'];<br>
            $this->identifica = $_POST['identifica'];<br>
            $this->id_user = $_POST['id_user'];<br>
            $this->legenda =date("HisdmY");<br>
            $arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];<br>
            $tamanho = 5000000; //5MB<br><br>
            //2º PARTE (VERIFICANDO A EXISTENCIA DO ARQUIVO E FAZENDO A VALIDACAO DO MESMO COM TRÊS CONDIÇÕES)<br><br>
            if(!empty($arquivo['name'])){<br>
                //VALIDANDO O TIPO DE IMAGEM<br>
                //echo $arquivo['type'];<br>
                if(!preg_match('/^(audio)\/(mpeg|mp3)$/', $arquivo['type'])){<br>
                    $error = '<script type="text/javascript">alert("INSERT - Somente podem ser enviados arquivos (MP3)");</script>';<br>
                }<br>

                <br><br>
                //VALIDANDO O TAMANHO DO ARQUIVO<br><br>
                if($arquivo['size'] > $tamanho){<br>
                    $error = '<script type="text/javascript">alert("INSERT - O áudio enviado extrapola o tamanho permitido");</script>';<br>
                }<br><br>


                //3º PARTE (ALTERANDO O NOME DO ARQUIVO E ENVIANDO PARA PASTA QUE LHE FOI DESTINADA)<br><br>                        
                if(count($error) == 0){<br>
                    $ext = pathinfo($arquivo['name']);<br>
                    $nome_imagem = $this->objfc->normalizaString($this->legenda).'.'.$ext['extension'];/**/<br>
                    $legenda = 'legenda';/**/<br>

                    <br><br>
                    $caminho_imagem = 'audios/'.$nome_imagem;<br>
                    $legenda = 'legenda';<br>
                    move_uploaded_file($arquivo['tmp_name'], $caminho_imagem);<br><br>
                    //CADASTRANDO AS INFORMAÇÕES
                    <br><br>

                    $cst = $this->con->conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO `aula_upload_arquivos` (`aula`,`identifica`,`id_user`,`legenda`, `arquivo`) VALUES (:aula,:identifica,:id_user, :legenda, :arquivo)  ;");<br>
                    $cst->bindParam(':aula', $this->objfc->tratarCaracter($this->aula, 1), PDO::PARAM_STR);<br>
                    $cst->bindParam(':identifica', $this->objfc->tratarCaracter($this->identifica, 1), PDO::PARAM_STR);<br>
                    $cst->bindParam(':id_user', $this->objfc->tratarCaracter($this->id_user, 1), PDO::PARAM_STR);<br>
                    $cst->bindParam(':legenda', $this->objfc->tratarCaracter($this->legenda, 1), PDO::PARAM_STR);<br>
                    $cst->bindParam(':arquivo', $nome_imagem, PDO::PARAM_STR);<br>
                    if($cst->execute()){<br>
                        header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);<br>
                        <br>
                    }else{<br>
                        //Erro de falha no programa//<br>
                        //header('location: http://localhost/definitivo/erro.php');<br>
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error: '.$ex->getMessage().'");</script>';<br>
                    }<br>
                }else{<br>
                    echo $error;<br>
                }<br>
            }else{<br>
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Escolha o arquivo para Upload");</script>';<br>
            }<br>
        }catch(PDOException $ex){<br>
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error: '.$ex->getMessage().'");</script>';<br>
        }<br>
    }<br>

}<br><br>
?><br>
```

Comment: Você esta só cadastrando, faça uma validação, um `select` no BD. Se retornar > 1 é pq você já tem o dado salvo, então faça `update` se não `insert`.

Comment: Exatamente, esse é o problema. Me falta, experiência suficiente para poder fazer essa ação. Eu precisava de um exemplo dentro desta programação.

Comment: Estou há mais de 2 semanas neste problema. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer algo semelhante a isso. Como você não especificou exatamente o que precisa usei como exemplo a coluna aula

```
$aula= "exemplo";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM aula_upload_arquivos WHERE aula=?");
$stmt->execute([$aula]); 
$exec= $stmt->fetch();

if ($exec) {
   // Existe aula, então faz o (update)
} else {
   // Não existe aula então cria uma nova (insert)
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, vou tentar seguir essa lógica

Comment: Guilherme, obrigado pelo sua disposição. Mas, como você citou, eu não fui muito claro na minha explicação. 
1) Não pode haver duplicação, 
2) O código de classe restringe em muito as ações que possam ser feitas dentro desse código. Algumas vezes, escreve algo, e a classe, simplesmente ignora.
3) Há uma outra parte do código que controla todo o sistema de classes, talvez, fosse melhor inserir aqui também

Comment: Vou incluir o código completo
<br><br><br><br>


<?php
require_once 'classes/Upload.class-pdo2.php';
require_once 'classes/Funcoes.class.php';

$objUp = new Upload();
$objFc = new Funcoes();

if(isset($_POST['btEnviar'])){
 $objUp->queryInsert();
}

if(isset($_POST['btAlterar'])){
 $objUp->queryUpdate();
}

if(!empty($_GET['acao'])){
 switch($_GET['acao']){
  case 'edit': $slt = $objUp->querySelecionar($_GET['id']); break;
  case 'delet': $objUp->queryDelete($_GET['id']); break; 
 }
}
?>

Comment: desculpa, não sei como faz para postar aqui

Comment: Não da para colocar nos comentários, edita a pergunta.

Comment: Espero que tenha melhorado a pergunta. :-P

Comment: Bacco, why do not you take advantage of it and answer the question? An IF loop was made with an MSQLI response and accurate in PDO. Another question, about CLASSES, IF, INSERT and also no answer. Why not help, instead of hinder?

Comment: é possível essa ação? 

$identifica = ($_POST['identifica'] + $_POST['id_user']) ;

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEMA RESOLVIDO:

01) Conforme indicado por @bacco, foi feito UNIQUE para um dos campos
02) No Cadastro das informações, foi inserido um dado dentro do campo que sempre será único, usando o nome do usuário e sua ID.